# Disabling Code Analysis On Local Builds

Tags: tfs, code-analysis, tfsbuild

I want to ask a question about Code Analysis.
We enabled code analysis at our projects and we created a policy that forces developers run CA before check-in. But the solution is very big and running CA costs alot of time each local build, as you know a developer build solution may be 10 - 20 times.

So, i want to disable CA at local builds; but at the same time we had to comply with policy.

Of course CA will be runned while TFS Builds..

Is is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the code analysis on all your projects. Then set in the build the code analysis option to "Always"

Answer (score 0):

To disable code analysis locally I modified microsoft.common.targets by including at the bottom:

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
</PropertyGroup>
```

but bear in mind that microsoft.common.targets file might be overwritten next time you upgrade, repair or patch visual studio.

(You can use same trick to disable nuget reget for all your local projects)